# Can a GPX track be imported into Lightroom (2020)?

Tags: lightroom, gps

I just started using Lightroom Classic Creative Cloud (Oct. 2020).
I'm impressed with it's geotagging capability combined with map quality.

Can a GPX track be imported into Lightroom?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you found in existing questions here regarding [gps and lightroom](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gps+lightroom)?